# Coulden't Toast message in onPostExecute in asyncTask

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

My app is crashing on `Toast` in `OnPostExecute`.

I tried to put `context` insted of `MainActivity()` as Context in Toast but it's throwing same exception

The exception is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

What is happening? How should I solve it?

I am calling this `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute` of another `AsyncTask`

```
 InsertInDateDb( MainActivity(), dateEntity).execute()
```

AsyncTask is in `MainActivity`

```
private class InsertInDateDb(var context: MainActivity, var dateEntity: DateEntity) :
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Boolean {
        val dateRoomDatabase: DateRoomDatabase = DateRoomDatabase.getDateDb(context)!!

        val dateEntity1 = dateEntity
        dateRoomDatabase!!.getDateDao().insertDate(dateEntity)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
        if (result!!) {

            try {
                Toast.makeText(
                   MainActivity(),
                    "Entry added to date database",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("tag", "Exception $e")
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you pass the context/MainActivity? Maybe there's an error.
I'd also change the context from context: MainActivity to context: Context.

Comment: @Colibri you are right. I am passing MainActivity() as context when calling asyncTask

Comment: but passing 'this' doesn't work because I am calling It from onPostExecute of another asyncTask. How should I solve that?

Comment: I've added my comments as an answer now, so the comments here don't become too many :) Hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

**MainActivity()** gives you **new instance** of **MainActivity**, which is not the **current running instance** of **MainActivity**.

You should use **this@MainActivity** or **applicationContext** instead.

```
1. Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

2. Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: @Makarand Please use just Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Answer (score 1):

Replace MainActivity() with context

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the observer pattern to send information to the activity from an AsyncTask.

It's easy, safe and elegant. Here's a sample.

```
class WriteToDiskAsync(private val writeToDiskListener: WriteToDiskListener) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, File?>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): File? {
        //whatever
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(survey: File?) {
        writeToDiskListener.writeToDiskFinished()
    }
}
```

Here's the interface:

```
interface WriteToDiskListener {

    fun writeToDiskFinished()
}
```

And the activity or fragment:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), WriteToDiskListener {
    //Your stuff...

    override fun writeToDiskFinished() {
        if (!isFinishing) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

The "!isFinishing" check is recommended to avoid exceptions in certain moments.

To call the AsyncTask from the MainActivity you just have to do this:

```
WriteToDiskAsync(this).execute()
```

Hope it helps.

Mauricio

Comment: ok, but How should I pass the reference of implemented interface while calling AsyncTask?

Comment: I have passed 'MainActivity()' for the reference of interface but it's still crashing

Comment: I edited my answer with the information you are asking for

Comment: I cannot pass 'this' for reference of interface. bcz it's in onPostExecute of another AysncTask hence it points to that Class not MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be in passing the context to the InsertInDateDb instance.

If this task is embedded in another task, it means you need to pass the context even sooner (by passing "this") or as suggested in Maurici Guell Hernandez' answer, use an interface, passing something like an "OnFinishedListener" to your AsyncTasks.

You'd create the OnFinishedListener right at the beginning (for example in the MainActivity), with an "onFinished" method in which you could Toast. 
Then pass the Listener to the AsyncTasks respectively and in the end call the "onFinished" method in postExecute, to run it / make it show the Toast :)

Try to keep in mind, that the context needs to be the instance of an actually running activity ("this") and not something that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use mainActivityContext for context in asysnTask;

```
var mainActivityContext= null
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
mainActivityContext=this
...
..
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just call your `AsynckTask` like this

```
    InsertInDateDb(this@MainActivity, dateEntity).execute()
```

and toast in `onPostExecute()` like this

```
 Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Entry added to date database",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object of your Activity like below

```
 lateinit var mActivity: Activity
```

Now set your activity to your activity object.

```
mActivity = this@YourActivity
```

Use `mActivity` to your Toast

```
Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Entry added to date database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```